# How to replace variable's name with a string in .js file?

Tags: javascript

I want to refer to a variable by another variable. 1st variable's value is a string equal to 2nd variable's name. How to do, say:

```
var1 = "var2";
var2 = [1,2,3];

console.log(var1[0]);
```

and get 1 instead of 'v'?

my code:

```
localStorage.setItem('scn', 'AR1');

var AR1 = [1,3,4,6];
var AR2 = [1,3,5,6];
var AS2 = [1,3,7,8,9,10];

here_idx = localStorage.getItem('scn').indexOf(1);
```

In this case here_idx is equal to 2 instead of 0.

I tried parsing it with an error. I don't know how to even search for such problem online. I tried.

Comment: Try in the same scope where you initialized var1: [var1][0]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One way to do it. But not recommended is as follows: (using eval() ).

It is fully legal and valid though:

```js
var2 = [1,2,3];
var1 = eval("var2");
console.log(var1[0]);
```

Comment: Using eval is not recommeded. See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Never_use_eval!)

Comment: I did say that already in my answer. But it is not illegal or invalid as it is fully supported. It is not a deprecated keyword.

Comment: It's the only suggested answer, that works in my case. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can use `window[varname]` to get a previously declared variable with `var` (not `let` or `const`) that is in the `window` scope.

Fiddle Since Snippets don't allow localstorage: https://jsfiddle.net/o27andcx/

```
var AR1 = [1,3,4,6];
var AR2 = [1,3,5,6];
var AS2 = [1,3,7,8,9,10];

localStorage.setItem('scn', 'AR1');

here_var = localStorage.getItem('scn');

here_idx = window[here_var];

console.log(here_idx);
```

Comment: Note that this will only work for variables declared with `var`, not those declared with `let` or `const`. If you want to make a variable global, it's usually clearer to declare it explicitly as a property of `window`: `window.AR1 = ...` etc.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Results in the same case as in my code.

Comment: @Warxuaroz that code does work here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/o27andcx/ So you must not being using it right or your code example doesn't show what you are actually doing

Answer (score 0):

You can assign variables from arrays with destructured assignment

```js
const [z, x, ,y] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
console.log(z, x, y);     //Outputs [1, 2, 4]
```

Comment: Would you expand this answer? I have no idea what happend here.

Answer (score 0):

"var2" and var2 are not the same. You can do something like the following

```
var1 = var2;
var2 = [1,2,3];

console.log(var1[0]); // outputs 1 not 'v'
```

or

```
var AR1 = [1,3,4,6];
localStorage.setItem('scn', AR1);

here_idx = localStorage.getItem('scn').indexOf(1);//outputs 0
```

Comment: That would work, but I need to keep var1 and var2 unchanged for later use.

Comment: Unless you change them variables will remain unchanged. So unsure what the issue is. What is the use case for assigning a variable name as string?

Comment: I'm following a scenario named AR1, which I want to know in every .html during the scenario, hence I store it in localStorage under 'scn'. I need to also know, where to go with my 'back' and 'next' buttons, hence the AR1 array with all the .htmls' names.